# hive query to collect twitter data per user

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hive

i am using hadoop with flume , hive and db derby i have twitter data in to hadoop in json formate
working fine now i need combine data as per user tweets like

data

```
{user_id:12,text:"abcd"}
{user_id:13,text:"dcba"}
{user_id:12,text:"efjh"}
{user_id:13,text:"hjfe"}
```

i need result like this

```
{user_id:12 , tweets:["abcd","efjh"]}
{user_id:13 , tweets:["dcba","hjfe"]}
```

my hive table is look like

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tweets (
created_at INT,
id STRING,
id_str STRING,
source STRING,
text STRING,
retweet_count INT,
favorite_count INT,
user_id INT,
user_id_str STRING,
user_name STRING,
user_screen_name STRING,
user_location STRING,
user_url STRING,
user_description STRING,
user_protected boolean,
user_followers_count INT,
user_friends_count INT,
user_listed_count INT,
user_statuses_count INT,
user_created_at INT,
user_favourites_count INT,
user_utc_offset INT,
user_lang STRING,
user_time_zone STRING,
user_geo_enabled boolean,
user_verified boolean
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde'
LOCATION '/user/data/twitter';
```

i need only two fields as output like in my required output example

```
{user_id:12 , tweets:["abcd","efjh"]}
{user_id:13 , tweets:["dcba","hjfe"]}
```

also need this in file format

> note: output as json format is not mandatory

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i have found solution for this question:

hive having a list of function that modified your query result in the above question case i have found a hive function that meet the required output of question.

function name is collect_set().

usage example of this function:

```
SELECT user_id , collect_set(text) FROM tweets GROUP BY user_id;
```

Result:

```
  user_id        text
user_id:12  ["abcd","efjh"]
user_id:13  ["dcba","hjfe"]
```